# How can I add a different classes for "next" and "previous" links with wp_link_pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `wp_link_pages` function and I want to add different div classes for  "next" and "previous" links (using 'next_or_number'   => 'next' arg).

I was trying to do it like this:

```
<?php
        $args = array(
        'before'           => '<div class="next">',
        'after'            => '</div>',
        'next_or_number'   => 'next',
    ); 

    wp_link_pages( $args ); ?>
```

Than I have a similar classes for both next and previous link.
But I need a "next" class for next link and "previous" class for previous link.

I've also tried something like this:

```
<?php $args = array(

'before'           => '<div class="page-link-next-prev">',
'after'            => '</div>',
'next_or_number'   => 'next',
'nextpagelink'     => __('<div class="next">Continue Reading</div>'),
'previouspagelink' => __('<div class="prev">Go Back</div>') ?>

<?php wp_link_pages( $args ); ?>
```

But than I have div class="next" inside link and it wraps only the text.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: First off, welcome to Stackoverflow. So Stackoverflow isn't exactly a good place for "I don't know how to code this, code this for me" which is how you're coming off, you probably mean to say, and should say something more like "I don't know how to code this, I've tried X, but doesn't work, what's wrong with X and how can I fix X.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianGrabowski and I am sorry for my question. I didn't mean that I need someone to code it for me. I just want to understand is it possible to do this with this function and maybe someone has done this before.
Once again I am sorry for my question format and my bad English.